# Performing deployment of application and restarting of domain in the same server

Tags: hudson

I am using hudson which will run scheduled builds from time to time.

Problem is that i configured a shell script which will be excuted to perform the deployment and also restarting of domain.

As hudson is on the same application server as the actual application.

My hudson will stop and also stop the shell script after the asadmin stop-domain command so it doesn't proceed to start back the domain.

What can i do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is right. Every process that Hudson starts will be destroyed when Hudson shuts down. So you need a way to have a process outside of Hudson pick up that signal. You can do that with a separate process that checks a directory periodically and performs an action according to files that will be created in that directory. The safest way is to code the action in the filename. However, a message to any non-Hudson process will do as well.